# VMplayer unable to "Open a Virtual Machine"

Tags: vmware-player

I have installed "Vmplayer" on my ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS.

I have created 3 virtual machines on the vmplayer but now after ubuntu update I am having problem while opening a virtual machine in vmplayer.

When I start vmplayer I get the vmplayer window with following options:

- create new virtual machine
- open virtual machines
- Upgrade
- Help

But whenever I go to "***open a virtual machine***" and select a virtual machine **nothing happens**.Vmplayer does not open that virtual machine. It just takes me back to home screen.

I tried running vmplayer with `sudo` and then I was able to open virtual machines. But earlier sudo rights were not needed.

What is happening? How do I solve this problem? I had a look at `/tmp/vmware-<user>/logs` but I didn't find any error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found answer to my question.

I don't know but somehow the permissions of the `~/vmware` (where virtual machines are stored) directory were changed and hence the problem.

The trick helped me is:

`sudo chmod 755 -R ~/vmware`

`sudo chown -R <user>:<user> ~/vmware`

Hope this helps!